# Ui-router not working on startup

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
I have set up within angular 1.5 the Ui-router as follows:

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
  .state('blank', {  url:'/blank', templateUrl: 'home/blank.html' })
 `enter code here` .state('verify', { url:'/verify/:type', templateUrl : 'update/verify.html', controller: function($scope, $stateParams, general) { general.verifyemail($stateParams.type);} })
  .state('home', {  url:'/', templateUrl: 'home/home.html' })
  .state('about', { url:'/about', templateUrl: 'about/about.html' })
  .state('faq', { url:'/faq', templateUrl: 'faq/faq.html' })
  .state('exercise', { url:'/exercise', templateUrl: 'practice/exercise.html' })
  .state('levels', { url:'/levels', templateUrl: 'practice/level.html' })
}]);
```

the router works when the app is already started but if you extend the url to include the path i.e. myapp/about and paste the url into a new browser window, the browser will open the app but go to the home page. If you paste the same url into the page already loaded, it goes to the right state.

I've obviously set it up wrong but I can't figure out why.

Comment: It should be myapp#/about no ? unless you changed this.

Comment: Sorted - many thanks to all the replies - it turned out the my js code had states calls which took preference over the url browser call.  When you try and modify an existing program it is not always easy to know what the rest of the code is doing!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use # before route name?

Like: `myapp/#/about`

Comment: Yes thanks - that was what I was using! - it is rally strange that it does not work first time round

Comment: Sorry I meant that's the address I've been using and not that it is now working.